# PHP date comparison (2 weeks)

Tags: php, date

```
$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d");
$maxBookingDate=strtotime('+2 weeks', $todaysDate);
$dateEntered = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST["Date"]);
$tableDate =$dateEntered->format('Y-m-d');
if ($tableDate < $todaysDate){
    echo "Date must be in the future";
}
if ($tabledate > $maxBookingDate){
    echo "Date must be no more than 2 weeks in advance";
}
```

Date comparison to make sure that the date a user enters is no more than two weeks in advance isn't working, what have I done wrong?

Comment: strtotime takes an int as second parameter, but $todaysDate has been made a string.

Comment: I would properly use micro time and convert i think...

Comment: date() returns string, strtotime() accepts int as second argument which is a time stamp.

When comparing date, you can use time stamp, which is int, but you don't compare two date string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `DateTime` classes all through out so that its easier to compare:

```
$todaysDate = new DateTime();
$maxBookingDate = new DateTime('+2 weeks');
$dateEntered = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['Date']);
if ($dateEntered < $todaysDate){
    echo "Date must be in the future";
} elseif ($dateEntered > $maxBookingDate){
    echo "Date must be no more than 2 weeks in advance";
}
```

In your code:

`$todaysDate` is a string, and you fed it inside `strtotime()` as your second parameter which is incorrect usage. The second parameter requires numeric value (timestamp).

Inside your if else statement, you're comparing strings. You should be comparing them as timestamps or DateTime objects instead, like the answer above.